# Retrieving relationships from relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have an application using Laravel 7. Within it, I have an "Account" model, this model has several "Profiles" and each "Profile" has several "Products".

How can I retrieve all the "Products" attached to certain "Accounts" in an optimal way.

Currently, I load all the "Profiles" linked to this "Account" and then all the "Products" linked to each "Profile". But I don't find this very optimized and have difficulties in sorting the returned data (in descending order).

I'm sure that Eloquent / Laravel allows to recover this directly, but I don't know how.

Thanks to you !

Comment: You can set one to many relationship and do eager loading

Answer (score 4):

```
Account::with(['profiles','profiles.products'])->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

eloquent has the relation 'Has Many Through' just for this kind of cases,
in your Account Model you could write something like:

```
class Account extends Model
{
public function products()
{
return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Profile::class);
}
}
```

now, you can get all product for specified account like:

```
$myAccountProducts=Account::find($account_id)->products()->get();
```

you can also specify foreign keys ...

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through